How do I manually set up timer driven interrupts on Portenta H7 Board?
I believe it's true to say that the Arduino Portenta H7 does not handle timer driven interrupts very well.
I'm trying to use an Arduino Portenta H7 and an MCP2515 chip to communicate with a couple electronic speed controllers. I've managed to get my control loop running without interrupts but would like to abstract a few of the tasks in my code, namely making sure throttle command updates are being sent often enough to avoid the watchdog on the controllers from timing out. I figured assigning that task to something that can manage executions in the background would be the safest option (such as a timer driven interrupt).
The problem I've run into is that I cannot find any reliable way to create and manage timers on the Portenta H7. I've found a couple of libraries, namely the stm32htxx_hal.h and the Portenta_H7_TimerInterrupt libraries. The former doesn't have many explicit instructions on setting up timers in the arduino IDE and the latter has one serious problem.
In the arduino post for the Portenta_H7_TimerInterrupt library, the creator explicitly states to not do anything too complicated in the ISR callback function such as Serial.xxx operations. I guess that means using the mcp2515 library is simply too complicated. If I don't actually request any throttle updates in the callback function, the code will run fine. I can actually do quite a bit there. But If I try to do anything with the serial monitor or the MCP2515, the MBED OS on the Portenta H7 will immediately crash and the device will become unrecognizable to my windows machine.
Are there better ways to accomplish this? I would like this and may other things to be tied to timer driven interrupts to help ensure those tasks are happing regularly and independent of any blocking that might be happening else-where in the code.
